# Nodejs - Does unhandled requests cause lack of resources?

Tags: node.js, express

When something wrong happens and I don't call res.end, res.json, etc then server just doesn't answer so it is supposed that there is something pending. Should I care about that? What if that happens many times?

Comment: Ideally request should be responded with some HTTP response else the client app (HttpClient) will continue to wait for response till the request time's out based on Request timeout set. It must process the request by res.end with valid HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0):

Unclosed or slow requests will cause increasing processing cost, loss of memory, etc. So yes, it is necessary to worry about it, especially in the heavy, complex pages.

You can use the [`connect-timeout`](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout) module for this:

```
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
app.post('/save', timeout('5s'), function (req, res, next) {
    setTimeout( 
        function() {
            res.json('ok')
        }, 100 
    );
})
```